# Using .htaccess redirect all files/directories to a subdirectory but exclude the homepage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I set up my web server having created a .htaccess file and subdirectory of 'www' in which I placed my Wordpress install.

Having run the install, everything appears to be redirecting as would be expected with the exception of the home page which throws a 404 error as the redirect rules contained in the .htaccess file are adding /www/ to the URL.

Guessing it's probably something simple, but need some objective help.

Obviously my actual domain has been substituted for 'domain.com'

```
# Turn off indexing of files and directories.
Options -Indexes

# Turn on rewrites.
RewriteEngine on

# Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Don't apply to URLs that go to existing files or folders.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Only apply to URLs that aren't already in the subdirectory.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www/

# Rewrite all those to insert the subdirectory name.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1

# Redirect the root folder.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ www/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's a simple fix just as I had first thought.

By replacing `[L,R=301]` in the final set of rules with `[L]` prevents the home page coming back to itself with the addition of the subdirectory.